# WiFi direct failure to connect Raspberry Pi to Android

Tags: raspberry-pi, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wpa-supplicant

I'm attempting to connect an Android Phone to a Raspberry Pi over WiFi Direct however when the Pi is the group owner (GO) it always fails to form a group. If I create a group on the Android device first and then have the Pi join it connects as expected and I can run iperf to test the connection.

On the Pi side I'm running the following commands with wpa_cli:

```
Selected interface 'p2p-dev-wlan0'

Interactive mode

 p2p_find
 OK
CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
 wps_pbc
 OK
P2P-DEVICE-FOUND 32:07:4d:78:91:6d p2p_dev_addr=32:07:4d:78:91:6d pri_dev_type=10-0050F204-5 name='[Phone] Galaxy S8' config_methods=0x188 dev_capab=0x25 group_capab=0x0 vendor_elems=1 new=1
P2P-PROV-DISC-PBC-REQ 32:07:4d:78:91:6d p2p_dev_addr=32:07:4d:78:91:6d pri_dev_type=10-0050F204-5 name='[Phone] Galaxy S8' config_methods=0x188 dev_capab=0x25 group_capab=0x0
P2P-GO-NEG-REQUEST 32:07:4d:78:91:6d dev_passwd_id=4 go_intent=0
p2p_connect 32:07:4d:78:91:6d pbc
 OK
P2P-FIND-STOPPED 
P2P-GO-NEG-SUCCESS role=GO freq=2462 ht40=0 peer_dev=32:07:4d:78:91:6d peer_iface=32:07:4d:78:11:6d wps_method=PBC
P2P-GROUP-FORMATION-FAILURE 
P2P-GROUP-REMOVED p2p-wlan0-1 GO reason=FORMATION_FAILED
```

And here's the log:

```
P2P-DEVICE-FOUND 32:07:4d:78:91:6d p2p_dev_addr=32:07:4d:78:91:6d pri_dev_type=10-0050F204-5 name='[Phone] Galaxy S8' config_methods=0x188 dev_capab=0x25 group_capab=0x0 vendor_elems=1 new=1
P2P-PROV-DISC-PBC-REQ 32:07:4d:78:91:6d p2p_dev_addr=32:07:4d:78:91:6d pri_dev_type=10-0050F204-5 name='[Phone] Galaxy S8' config_methods=0x188 dev_capab=0x25 group_capab=0x0
P2P-GO-NEG-REQUEST 32:07:4d:78:91:6d dev_passwd_id=4 go_intent=0
P2P-FIND-STOPPED 
P2P-GO-NEG-SUCCESS role=GO freq=2462 ht40=0 peer_dev=32:07:4d:78:91:6d peer_iface=32:07:4d:78:11:6d wps_method=PBC
p2p-wlan0-1: Could not connect to kernel driver
Using interface p2p-wlan0-1 with hwaddr f6:f7:f3:7e:19:d6 and ssid "DIRECT-dK"
Failed to set beacon parameters
p2p-wlan0-1: Could not connect to kernel driver
Interface initialization failed
p2p-wlan0-1: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
p2p-wlan0-1: AP-DISABLED 
p2p-wlan0-1: Unable to setup interface.
Failed to initialize AP interface
p2p-wlan0-1: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
p2p-wlan0-1: AP-DISABLED 
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface p2p-wlan0-1 wasn't started
p2p-wlan0-1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=f6:f7:f3:7e:19:d6 reason=3 locally_generated=1
P2P-GROUP-FORMATION-FAILURE 
P2P-GROUP-REMOVED p2p-wlan0-1 GO reason=FORMATION_FAILED
p2p-wlan0-1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=f6:f7:f3:7e:19:d6 reason=3 locally_generated=1
nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-wlan0-1 disabled_11b_rates=0
P2P-DEVICE-LOST p2p_dev_addr=32:07:4d:78:91:6d
p2p-dev-wlan0: WPS-TIMEOUT Requested operation timed out
```

In the log there's an obvious error 'p2p-wlan0-1: Could not connect to kernel driver' but I wouldn't know where to look next to investigate this?

Comment: how did you get this log? I don't know the answer to your question rn but I'm working on the same thing and I will definitely report back once I figure it out

Comment: @Dyskord wpa_supplicant has a command line option '-f' that lets you specify where the log file should be created. I'm not sure what level of logging I was using but there is also a '-d' or '-dd' option which increases the verbosity.